# Square root Iteration using x1 = (x0 - a / x0) / 2

Tags: iteration

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public static double Sqrt (double a){
     double xOld = a / 2;
     double xNew = 0;
     while (Math.abs(xOld - xNew) >= 0.0001 {
              xNew = (xOld + a / xOld) / 2;
              xNew = xOld;
    }
}
```

I need to use the algorithm x1 = (x0 - a / x0) / 2 to find the approximate square root of a number. a is the original number and x0 starts at the value a / 2. When I run this code I get 12.5 (which is a / 2). What i need help on is what xNew value to initialize and the last line to the while loop. Thanks for any help

Comment: Where did you get this formulae?

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS ON FOR SIZE:

```
Public static double Sqrt(double a) throws IllegalArgumentException {

     if (a < 0.0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

     double aSqrt = a / 2.0;
     while (Math.abs(a - aSqrt*aSqrt) >= 0.0001) {  // I'd use a smaller tolerance
          double aSqrtPrev = aSqrt;
          aSqrt = (aSqrtPrev + a / aSqrtPrev) / 2.0;
     }

     return aSqrt ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is `xOld = xNew` at the end of your loop, as the way it is set up now, you immediately overwrite the value of `xNew` that you just calculated.

But the above is not enough.  With `xNew` and `xOld` equal at the end of the loop, you guarantee that the while loop will exit on the next pass, given the test condition.  Try using a different condition for the while loop, such as `Math.abs(a - xNew*xNew) >= 0.0001` or similar.

Another way to do it would be to keep your test condition as-is, but then you would have to swap the order of the two statements in the while loop, still do the assignment `xOld = xNew`.

Comment: no, you need to introduce a temporary variable `temp = xNew`, then after changing `xNew`, replace `Xnew = xOld` with `xOld = temp`.

Comment: That would work, too.   It adds an extra variable compared to the way suggested in the third paragraph above, but may be easier to conceptualize.